# iOS App Extension App Store Provisioning: Getting error: The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: ios, code-signing, ios-app-extension

I'm developing an app in Adobe AIR for iOS which has app extension.

When I code sign app extension with Adhoc provisioning profile, it works fine.

But when I code sign app extension with App store and create `ipa` file, I'm getting the following error while installing on device:

> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing
>   Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those
>   specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I didn't find the solution for this question, I would like to answer my findings.

For installing app on test devices, your app needs to be signed with Ad-hoc provisioning profile.

> *"App Store provisioning profiles do not allow for a distribution built application to be installed on an Apple device. To install your
>   distribution ready application on a device, you must create an Ad Hoc
>   provisioning profile."*

But there is a catch here. If Ad-hoc provisioning profile is already present on test device, you can install app signed with App Store provisioning profile.

iOS App Extension have its own provisioning profile. Even if Ad-hoc provisioning profile for App Extension is installed on device, you cannot install app with app extension signed with App Store provisioning profile on test device.

**Solution**: Use TestFlight to test App Store build on test devices.

Answer (score 0):

Extension app have its own provisioning profile and entitlements, check https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle to see your app extension's entitlements, it should match the entitlements in xcode project.